# What's the correct nginx rewrite expression for this URL pattern?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm going bananas trying to get a Nginx rewrite rule to work. An example URL that the rewrite pattern should match is:

```
https://test.mydomaind.com/abc.php?id=1
```

My rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/abc\.php?id=(.*)$ https://test.mydomain.com/page/$1 permanent;
```

But this returns a 404 with the example URL.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? When I leave out the query string parameter in the condition the rewrite does work and the user is redirected 301:

```
rewrite ^/abc\.php$ https://test.mydomain.com/page permanent; # THIS WORKS
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Anything from the `?` onwards is the query string and is not considered when matching the URI to `locations` or `rewrite` statements.

The query string (or arguments) are accessible in the `$request_uri` and `$query_string` (aka `$args`) variables and the family of variables prefixed with `$arg_`.

You could implement something similar with:

```
location = /abc.php {
    return 301 https://test.mydomain.com/page/$arg_id;
}
```

If you need to test for the presence of an `id=` argument, you will need to resort to `map` or `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks so much! I totally missed that. Feels like I'm one step closer, however the redirect doesn't quite produce the desired result yet. The $arg_id variable seems to be empty. Testing with multiple arguments I get a URL that looks like https://test.mydomain.com/page////, where I would expect https://test.mydomain.com/page/<id>/<arg1>/<arg2>. Any pointers?

Comment: Hi Richard, could you have a look at my comment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957039/whats-the-correct-nginx-rewrite-expression-for-this-url-pattern/39960228#39960228